# Does Visual Studio 2010 Beta support .NET 2.0 projects? What about SQL 2005 DBs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0, .net-4.0, compatibility

Does Visual Studio 2010 Beta support .NET 2.0 projects?

What about opening SQL 2005 *.ndf files with the new IDE?
(meaning mdf files included in the project like App_Data DBs in web applications etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. VS2010 targets .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/06/06/multi-targeting-of-web-projects-using-visual-studio-2010-beta1.aspx))

DB projects have been somewhat superceded by the recent [GDR R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed) Database project release. It's a free download for **team editions** of Visual Studio 2008

This type of project was originally part of the database edition of Visual Studio.

It has the ability to import a schema from an existing database, perform schema compares, support multiple targets (System Test, UAT, Production, etc), perform TSQL static code analysis, and produce standalone deployment artifacts.

Comment: Can you please provide additional brief info about GDR?
I thought about installing VS2010 Pro edition, should I expect pain?

Comment: and data dude is included in dev edition of team system in 2010