# Can I use .NET 4.0 beta in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0

There are some really great features in .NET 4.0 that I would like to start using but I am not comfortable making the change to VS 2010 just yet. Is there a way to use the .NET 4.0 beta in VS 2008?

Comment: You happy using the .net 4.0 *beta* but your not happy with vs2010. What's your reason for using one beta but not the other? Personally, neither should be used for live apps while they are still in beta.

Comment: @Simon: Ever consider perhaps not everyone can afford the latest Visual Studio upgrade? I personally think it's lame MS requires developers to upgrade to their latest dev tool to develop for the latest framework version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I develop for .NET Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836410/can-i-develop-for-net-framework-4-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 8):

no, this is not possible, .NET 4.0 requires VS 2010 to be able to target/build.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is - the IDE is usually tied to a particular version of the framework, and 2008 has been the first version to allow you to target a "non-native" (so to speak) version of the framework, instead of just the matching version.

While Microsoft might add support later, I wouldn't expect them to, though I would expect 2010 to be able to target different versions aside from 4.0 (I haven't used it, so it may do this and I don't know it). Update: [According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960904), 2010 targets 2, 3, 3.5, and 4.

To target 4.0, you'll have to use 2010 - at least for now, and probably indefinitely.

Comment: Adding .NET 4.0 support to Visual Studio 2008 is a costly operation. Besides this, Microsoft wants us to buy Visual Studio 2010. Two reasons why Microsoft will not add .NET 4.0 support to Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Some of new stuff that will be shipped with 4.0 were released as "extensions" and "CTPs", for example [Parallels Extensions for .NET 3.5](http://zvolkov.com/blog/post/2009/06/12/Parallels-Extensions-for-NET-Framework-35.aspx) will eventually be included in 4.0 but you can start playing with it now in VS 2008.

Comment: By all means try it out, but be aware there are some significant differences in the way things work between the parallel extensions for 3.5 and the task parallel library in 4.0.

Comment: @Simon P Stevens Thanks, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

No, VS 2008 Multi Targeting option only support .NetFramework 3.5 , 3.0 , 2.0

so it has a Backward Compatability, So You have to Use VS 2010 for .netFramework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

AS the people here already said, no.

But if you want to check out some of .net 4 features you could download the already aging [Parallel Exetnsions CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en) and try it out with Visual Studio 2008.

It not much...