# Can I use .net 4.0 beta without having vs2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use .NET 4.0 beta in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008)

I have VS 2008 professional, and yesterday installed .net 4.0 Beta 1 (without vs2010).
I want to try parallel Fx lib, but I don't know how to add .net 4.0 references. It is possible to use 4.0 version without visual studio 2010?

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: Not a dupe. You can use .NET 4.0 without installing VS2010, but you can't use C# 4 from VS2008. They're different problems.

Comment: The question I linked to explicitly says .NET 4.0, not C# 4.0.  There is a question about C# 4.0 and VS2008, it is just not the one I linked to.

Comment: Sorry, my bad expression of it: you can use .NET 4.0 without installing VS2010, but you can't use .NET 4 from VS2008. So the answer to the exact question expressed here in the last sentence if "yes" - but it sounds like ksirg didn't really mean to ask that question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at:

[Can I use .NET 4.0 beta in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: Where did he say he wanted to use VS2008?

Comment: His first five words. "I have VS 2008 professional."

Comment: That says he *has* it. It doesn't say he wants to use it to try .NET 4.0 :) (To be fair, I had completely failed to spot that first time. Was it edited in, or am I just being silly?) Anyway, he can certainly use the command line tools.

Comment: Yes I want use .net 4.0 with vs 2008 and this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008 say everything I wanted to know ;)

Comment: Fair enough then. I'll just sit here looking stupid then :) It isn't the first time and it won't be the last...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use it from the command line, yes.

I seem to remember that a lot of Parallel Extensions is now in mscorlib or System.Core, so you probably don't need to add any references...

For example, this just compiled without anything else:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Task<int> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 10);
        Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the compilers (like csc.exe or vbc.exe) directly. They should be installed at:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0 or something close to that.

But if you want to do 4.0 development in Visual Studio, you'll probably need to install VS 2010.