# Can I (and how do I) target .net 4 with vs 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0-beta-2

VS2010 beta 2 is sloowwww on my machine. I'd like to start playing with .net 4 though. Can my vs 2008 solution's target .net 4 beta 2? How?

Comment: Sorry. I just noticed this is a dupe (couldn't find it on first search). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't target .NET 4.0 using VS 2008.

To speed up, you can try to create this key in Registry (worked for me):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics]
"DisableHWAcceleration"=dword:00000001
```

More info here [Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 editor performance fix running on a virtual machine](http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2009/10/19/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-editor-performance-fix-running-on-a-virtual-machine.aspx) and [Graphics Rendering Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx)

Comment: vs2010 is fast now. I'm accepting this cause it both answered my question and solved the speed issue. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't you need at least visual studio 2010 to target .net 4.0