# vs 2008 and .NET 4

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0

Can i develope .net 4 application with vs 2008?

Comment: You could develop .NET 4 applications with NotePad if you wanted. You just have to compile by hand...

Answer (score 5):

No. You need VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can download visual studio express which is free.  That will allow you to create .Net 4.0 applications.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4 is quite different from previous versions, and VS2008 doesn't support this. At least for now you have to use VS2010 to target .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before, see:

[Can I (and how do I) target .net 4 with vs 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743525/can-i-and-how-do-i-target-net-4-with-vs-2008)

So it appears you cannot. .NET 4 definitely had a beta, and I was thinking that was available for VS2008, but I guess I was mistaken and it was only available with the VS2010 beta.