# Can i use .net framework 4 with visual studio 2008 IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, ide, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use .NET 4.0 beta in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008)

Hot can I use visual studio 2008 IDE with .net framework 4?

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the general consensus is "no"

[Can I use .NET 4.0 beta in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 2):

No, VS 2008 **Multi Targeting** option only support .NetFramework 3.5 , 3.0 , 2.0

so it has a Backward Compatability, So You have to Use VS 2010 for .netFramework 4.0