# Will we be able to use vs2008 with .NET framework 4.0 final release?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0

I know the answer for the beta was no ([Can I use .NET 4.0 beta in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008)) but I was wondering if with the final release it would be different?

Thanks

Leo

Comment: I doubt it. But the VS2010 RTM was released yesterday, so jump on the bandwagon and install that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.  VS2010 is the first version to properly support multiple framework versions, VS2008 is stuck with 2.0 and 3.5