# Trouble upgrading to .NET 4 with VS2008. What am I missing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded the .NET 4 framework from Microsoft here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en

I installed and rebooted.

When I go to compile options --> target framework... .NET 4 isn't on the list.

Is .net 4 not compatible with VS2008?  It would be nice if Microsoft stated that somewhere...

Comment: possible dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 2):

You cannot target .NET 4 in Visual Studio 2008.  You will need to upgrade to VS 2010 if you want to target .NET 4.0, or use a .NET 4 assembly in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Compatible yes (as it works when installed), but you cannot target .NET 4 using VS2008.