# C# .net 4 charting development in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, charts, .net-4.0

A previous user of my old computer had managed to develop charting controls in a c# project using Visual Studio 2008.

Now, the computer has been replaced and I can no longer do this.

I have read that .net 4 is incompatible with VS2008 - but then I know that the charting was working before.

Does anyone have any ideas how this problem could be solved??

If it helps, the controls were in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting (in case it is non standard library)

I have .net 4 (may be client profile) installed on the machine, but VS only shows upto 2.5 in the options. Is it possible to add it manually? Perhaps this is what was previously done?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use VS2010 alone. You'll not be able to use .Net 4.0 proj in VS2008.

some related post.

[Can I use .NET 4.0 beta in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: As I say, it was definitely running last week on the old pc, even if it not officially supported. But nvm, I have downloaded Visual c# 2010 instead.